Create Service end point using Rest API AD Server 2020
I tried to create a Service endpoint in Azure DevOps Server 2020  using Rest API.
The Server endpoint is created only when PAT has full access. If I choose customised scopes along with Service Connections(Read, query & manage), the unauthorized error is thrown.
Can anyone assist with it?

Hi @Selva, have checked my answer below? Try to assign your PAT with vso.serviceendpoint_manage and Tokens (Read & Manage) scopes in Azure DevOps Server 2020. Then your API should work as expected.

Hi @ZiyangLiu-MSFT
I am using AD Server 2020.0.2. I created PAT with Service endpoint (Read, query & manage). Still it throws unauthorised error.
Service endpoint creates only the PAT has full access.

Hi @Selva,  as I mentioned, when you are using Azure DevOps Server 2020 you need assign your PAT with Service endpoint (Read, query & manage) and also Tokens (Read & Manage) scopes.  I can reproduce the 401 error when only select Service endpoint (Read, query & manage) scope and it works fine when I select **Tokens (Read & Manage) ** at the same time.

Hi @ZiyangLiu-MSFT,
After adding Tokens (Read & Manage) scope, i am able create service endpoint successfully.

Hi @Selva, it's great to know my answer works for you. Would you please let me know if you have any other question about this issue?

I can reproduce the issue when using Azure DevOps Server 2020.0.2 and Azure DevOps Server 2020.1.2.

According to Endpoints - Create, the scope should be vso.serviceendpoint_manage.

Testing on my side using a PAT with scope vso.serviceendpoint_manage, it works as expected on Azure DevOps Server 2022 and Azure DevOps Service.
Workaround
According to my test, on Azure DevOps Server 2020, in addition to Service endpoint (Read, query & manage) you also need to select Tokens (Read & Manage).

